# Inversing number: what is the fastest operation? Using bitwise operation or Using if statement?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bit-manipulation

I want to inverse a number in shell. my number value have only 2 possible values: 1 and 0. If my number is 1 I want to inverse to 0 and if it's 0 I want to inverse it to 1

What could be the faster operation to do it?

**1) Operation1: using if statement**

```
if [ x -eq 1 ]; then
    x=0
else
    x=1
fi
```

**2) Operation2: using bitwise operation (xor)**

```
let x^=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are programming in shell then surely speed is not your primary concern? Especially not micro-optimizations like this.

In any case, the speed would greatly depend on the shell you choose to use, and the specific version of that shell. The tags suggest bash, but you don't actually say.

The only advice I can give is to test it and see; write yourself a benchmark that does this a million times and then find out which runs quickest.

Then, when you're done testing all that in bash, try dash. It's said the be faster, if perhaps less feature rich.